# namedtuple pickling fails when variable name doesn't match typename

Tags: python, pickle, namedtuple

The python code below fails with the error `pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.SpecialName'>: it's not found as __main__.SpecialName`

```
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple

different_SpecialName = namedtuple('SpecialName', 'foo bar')
def save():
    foo = different_SpecialName(1, 2)
    with open('foosave.pkl', 'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(foo, f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    save()
```

This seems like bad behaviour of the `pickle` module, as it depends on the correctness of a *variable name*. Changing `different_SpecialName` to `SpecialName` and re-running the code allows it to complete successfully. Changing the code to the below, where a variable with `SpecialName` is instantiated to be the same value as `different_SpecialName`, also lets the code run successfully

```
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple

different_SpecialName = namedtuple('SpecialName', 'foo bar')

## create new variable with 'correct' name
SpecialName = different_SpecialName

def save():
    # foo = different_SpecialName(1, 2)
    foo = SpecialName(1, 2)
    with open('foosave.pkl', 'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(foo, f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    save()
```

My questions: is this fundamentally a `pickle` (and `cPickle`) bug? It seems like `pickle` shouldn't be looking up the class definition by using the name of the variable (although, I'm not sure what else it could do). Or, instead, is this an issue with the `namedtuple` API? I browsed the [`namedtuple` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) and couldn't find anything that explicitly told me to name my  `namedtuple` variables the same as my `typename` argument (the first argument to the `namedtuple()` function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. [`pickle` requires](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) that

> the class definition must be importable and live in the same module as when the object was stored.

From the perspective of the `namedtuple`'s `__reduce__` method, the type name is `SpecialName` (that's what you passed it after all). So when unpickling, it will try to import the module it was declared in and look for `SpecialName`. But since you didn't save it as `SpecialName`, it can't find it.

Without resorting to `namedtuple`s, you can produce the exact same problem with:

```
class Foo:
    pass
Bar = Foo
del Foo
```

and trying to pickle and unpickle a `Bar()`; under the hood, you've effectively done the same thing with your mismatched names for a `namedtuple`.

Comment: great, so it's the `namedtuple` documentation failing to warn the user that mismatching names can result in errors.

Comment: Well, every example given matches the `typename` argument with the name the result is assigned to, and the very first line notes that the class returned uses the `typename` argument. Adding a warning for every non-standard usage would clutter the docs quite a bit.

Comment: I disagree, it would take a brief one line to comment on the quite nonstandard requirement that the two names must match exactly.